# Alternative pattern to "editing" numpy array by changing values via boolean indexing

Tags: python, numpy, torch

When doing scientific computing, I often find myself writing lines of code like:

`waiting_times[state==s] = find_waiting_times(s, state[state == s].shape)`

I want to update the values of `waiting_times` for members in a particular state (`s`), so I use the boolean index `[state==s]` to "select" those members and then I provide an array of the right shape (ie: as many entries as there are members of that state).

In the latest `torch` nightly for M1 GPU acceleration, this behavior isn't possible ("operator 'aten::*index_put_impl*' is not current implemented for the MPS device"), but I also wonder if there's a better pattern out there in general. What's the right way to do this kind of "editing" of a subset of an array? What are the efficiency trade-offs of different methods?

Comment: You might want to clarify (in the subject line) that this is a torch/gpu issue, not a numpy one.

Comment: @hpaulj The short-term reason I need to change this is because it's not yet implemented in torch, but the actual motivation for asking is because I wonder if this pattern is any good in the first place. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a generally better way of doing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that kind of indexing.  Sometimes it's more convenient to use an indexing tuple produced by `np.nonzero(state==s)`, but the effect (and speed should be similar).